# How to customize the fusion Gantt chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, fusioncharts, gantt-chart

I am trying to implement Gantt Chart in Fusion Chart. But, I am not able to find few customizing options. Following are the options I require to implement on the Fusion Gantt Chart,

1. How to customize  or reduce the size of the milestone?
2. How to customize the Y-axis data label as hyperlink? [with reference to picture, the labels such as Identify Customers, Survey 500 customers, etc. must be an hyperlink which will help us to drilldown to data level information]
3. Is there any possible way to change the shape of the milestone to triangle other than polygon or star?

[image: I tried implementing this]

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var smoPlan = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'gantt',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '750',
    height: '500',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
        "caption": "Social Media Optimization",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subCaption": "Project Plan",
        "subCaptionFontSize": "12",
        "milestoneFont": "Times New Roman",
        "milestoneFontSize": "15",
         "labelLink": "http://www.fusioncharts.com/"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "start": "08/01/2014",
          "end": "08/31/2014",
          "label": "Aug '14"
        }, {
          "start": "09/01/2014",
          "end": "09/30/2014",
          "label": "Sep '14"
        }, {
          "start": "10/01/2014",
          "end": "10/31/2014",
          "label": "Oct '14"
        }, {
          "start": "11/01/2014",
          "end": "11/30/2014",
          "label": "Nov '14"
        }, {
          "start": "12/01/2014",
          "end": "12/31/2014",
          "label": "Dec '14"
        }, {
          "start": "01/01/2015",
          "end": "01/31/2015",
          "label": "Jan '15"
        }, {
          "start": "02/01/2015",
          "end": "02/28/2015",
          "label": "Feb '15"
        }, {
          "start": "03/01/2015",
          "end": "03/31/2015",
          "label": "Mar '15"
        }]
      }],
      "processes": {
        "fontsize": "12",
        "isbold": "1",
        "align": "left",
        "process": [{
          "label": "Identify Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Survey 500 Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Interpret Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Market Analysis"
        }, {
          "label": "Brainstorm concepts"
        }, {
          "label": "Define Ad Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Design & Develop"
        }, {
          "label": "Mock test"
        }, {
          "label": "Documentation"
        }, {
          "label": "Start Campaign"
        }]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "task": [{
          "id": "1",
          "start": "08/04/2014",
          "end": "08/10/2014",
          "color": "#000000",
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "start": "08/08/2014",
          "end": "08/19/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "3",
          "start": "08/19/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "4",
          "start": "08/24/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "5",
          "start": "09/02/2014",
          "end": "09/21/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "6",
          "start": "09/21/2014",
          "end": "10/06/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "7",
          "start": "10/06/2014",
          "end": "01/21/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "8",
          "start": "01/21/2015",
          "end": "02/19/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "9",
          "start": "01/28/2015",
          "end": "02/24/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "10",
          "start": "02/24/2015",
          "end": "03/27/2015"
        }]
      },
      //Adding milestones to task with id 7 and 10
      "milestones": {
        "milestone": [{
          "date": "1/21/2015",
          "taskid": "7",
          "color": "#f8bd19",
          "shape": "star",
          "tooltext": "Successful Completion of Development",
          "label": "Development Complete",
          "color": "#587B17"
        }, {
          "date": "3/28/2015",
          "taskid": "10",
          "color": "#f8bd19",
          "shape": "star",
          "tooltext": "Successful Completion of Campaign",
          "label": "Campaign Complete",
          "color": "#4838D2"
        }]
      }


    }
  }).render();
});

HTML Code
 -->
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can customize or reduce the size of the milestone by using the "radius" attribute under the "milestone" object like `radius: 5`
2. You can customize the Y-axis data label as hyperlink by using the "link" attribute under the "process" object like `link: "https://www.fusioncharts.com/"`. This attribute supports all kinds of FusionCharts link formats.
   Reference:
   https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down#simple-links
3. To change the shape of the milestone to triangle you need to set the "shape" attribute to "polygon" and set the "numSides" attribute to "3" under the "milestone" object like `numSides: 3`

Reference sample: http://jsfiddle.net/srishti_fc/w9bnt24L/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize or reduce and change the shape of the milestone please refer [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/gantt-chart#add-milestones-to-a-chart)

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var smoPlan = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'gantt',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '750',
    height: '500',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
        "caption": "Social Media Optimization",
        "captionFontSize": "14",
        "subCaption": "Project Plan",
        "subCaptionFontSize": "12",
        "milestoneFont": "Times New Roman",
        "milestoneFontSize": "15"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "start": "08/01/2014",
          "end": "08/31/2014",
          "label": "Aug '14"
        }, {
          "start": "09/01/2014",
          "end": "09/30/2014",
          "label": "Sep '14"
        }, {
          "start": "10/01/2014",
          "end": "10/31/2014",
          "label": "Oct '14"
        }, {
          "start": "11/01/2014",
          "end": "11/30/2014",
          "label": "Nov '14"
        }, {
          "start": "12/01/2014",
          "end": "12/31/2014",
          "label": "Dec '14"
        }, {
          "start": "01/01/2015",
          "end": "01/31/2015",
          "label": "Jan '15"
        }, {
          "start": "02/01/2015",
          "end": "02/28/2015",
          "label": "Feb '15"
        }, {
          "start": "03/01/2015",
          "end": "03/31/2015",
          "label": "Mar '15"
        }]
      }],
      "processes": {
        "fontsize": "12",
        "isbold": "1",
        "align": "left",
        "process": [{
          "label": "Identify Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Survey 500 Customers"
        }, {
          "label": "Interpret Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Market Analysis"
        }, {
          "label": "Brainstorm concepts"
        }, {
          "label": "Define Ad Requirements"
        }, {
          "label": "Design & Develop"
        }, {
          "label": "Mock test"
        }, {
          "label": "Documentation"
        }, {
          "label": "Start Campaign"
        }]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "task": [{
          "id": "1",
          "start": "08/04/2014",
          "end": "08/10/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "start": "08/08/2014",
          "end": "08/19/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "3",
          "start": "08/19/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "4",
          "start": "08/24/2014",
          "end": "09/02/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "5",
          "start": "09/02/2014",
          "end": "09/21/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "6",
          "start": "09/21/2014",
          "end": "10/06/2014"
        }, {
          "id": "7",
          "start": "10/06/2014",
          "end": "01/21/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "8",
          "start": "01/21/2015",
          "end": "02/19/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "9",
          "start": "01/28/2015",
          "end": "02/24/2015"
        }, {
          "id": "10",
          "start": "02/24/2015",
          "end": "03/27/2015"
        }]
      },
      //Adding milestones to task with id 7 and 10
      "milestones": {
        "milestone": [{
          "date": "1/21/2015",
          "taskid": "7",
          "color": "#f8bd19",
          "numSides": "3",
          // "shape": "star",
          "tooltext": "Successful Completion of Development",
          "label": "Development Complete",
          "color": "#587B17"
        }, {
          "date": "3/28/2015",
          "taskid": "10",
          "color": "#f8bd19",
          "shape": "star",
          "tooltext": "Successful Completion of Campaign",
          "label": "Campaign Complete",
          "color": "#4838D2"
        }]
      }


    }
  }).render();
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/u8nm6b2w/)